# I use routes in my Node.JS app and when I try to open one of the routes from the browser I get an error

Tags: javascript, node.js

That's my app. When I try to open ip/delete I get an error

> Cannot GET /delete

I'm following this tutorial, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_express_framework.htm

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        console.log("Got a GET request");
        res.send('GBArena Labs');
})

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
        console.log("Got a POST request");
})

app.delete('/delete', function(req, res) {
        res.send('Delete');
        console.log("Got a DELTE request");
})

app.listen(8081);
```

Comment: How are you trying to "open" your `delete` route? By writing it on the browser's location bar?

Comment: Yes, here it is 
http://35.185.72.190/delete

Comment: Gotcha, you're sending a `GET` request but you didn't define a get route. You should send a `DELETE` request instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't navigate to a DELETE. You have to send a DELETE request. In example :

`<a href="/delete">My delete link<a/>` will be sent as a GET request and not a DELETE.

In order to hit your delete endpoint, you would have to use a ajax library like jquery $.ajax and using

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/delete',
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

from the client side.

There are many ways, but i would suggest you looking into : [HTTP verbs](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to call the route without the /delete and use the HTTP verb DELETE from a REST client such as Fiddler or Postman.

Answer (score 0):

First, you try to access by `ip/delete` endpoint. I assume you will get an error because you are not using the port of the application (you have to access by ip:port/delete)

You have to know about the usage of DELETE method. When you try to directly access the `ip/delete` endpoint, your browser will set it as GET method while in your application, there is not GET method for `ip/delete`